# Angular wrapper of JS library doesn't load styles

Tags: javascript, css, angular, components, wrapper

I want to use this library https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#date-range in my application. But it has to be angular component so for the first time in my short career I wanted to create wrapper of library but I think I did something wrong becouse It doesn't looke like original picker.

This is how it should looks like:
[image]

And this is how it looks like as my angular component:

[image]

Also when I want to select only month or year it looks weird:

[image]

Ok so now time to see my component code:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit} from 
'@angular/core';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker';
declare var $;


@Component({
selector: 'cb-daterangepicker',
templateUrl: './daterangepicker.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./daterangepicker.component.scss']
})
export class DaterangepickerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

@Input()
datepickerOptions: DatepickerOptions;

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
}

ngOnInit() {

}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).datepicker();

    $('.input-daterange input').each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker('clearDates');
    });
}

}
```

As You see there is no for example selection of range, or just start and end dates, it simply looks different so I thought it becouse not loaded styles but I might be wrong. I need Your help Guys, maybe my wrapper isn't correctly done?

*Network console with styles:

[image]

Addin styles to index.html and angular.json helped with some things:

[image]

But still range between dates is not highlighted..

Comment: Did you follow the steps in [dependencies](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#dependencies) section? It says you need to generate a standalone .css file.

Comment: It means that I have for example copy/paste styles to my daterangepicker.component.scss?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that bootstrap is correctly loaded ? you have to check this first and you have to check if the css for the library is loaded afterwards.
try to check that with the browser network console :)
othewise try to call the library style with the cdn :

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css

Comment: Can You tell me how to check this in console? I have to put some console.log in my component?

Comment: I have added screenshot from this console in my question

Comment: could you please show me your css calls in your source code

Comment: Only in component file: styleUrls: ['./daterangepicker.component.scss'] and in this file I paste some styles from https://gist.github.com/bojanv91/aeeacd9910b6c5547478

Comment: you have to use it with the original bootstrap-datepicker.css file please try to add the css call  <link rel=“stylesheet” href=“https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css” /> in the main index.html (just for testing) and this should work afterwards you have to call the style properly in your  angular.json file

Comment: I did it as You said (added this styles in index.html) and still the same problem :(

Comment: Ok when I've added "node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" in angular.json it looks better. But still I have some problems, for example range between dates is not highlited. Do You think it is problem with styles?

Comment: try to add the js file in the angular.json also